# Wordpress logo upload option in theme panel

Tags: plugins, wp-query, theme-development, logo

Hello every one i am facing one issue in adding logo option in my theme panel of wordpress i am using this code

```
function logo_display()
{
    ?>
        <input type="file" name="logo" /> 
        <?php echo get_option('logo'); ?>
   <?php
}
function handle_logo_upload()
{
    if(!empty($_FILES["demo-file"]["tmp_name"]))
    {
        $urls = wp_handle_upload($_FILES["logo"], array('test_form' => FALSE));
        $temp = $urls["url"];
       return $temp;   
    }  
    return $option;
}
function display_theme_panel_fields()
{
    add_settings_section("section", "All Settings", null, "theme-options");
    add_settings_field("logo", "Logo", "logo_display", "theme-options", "section");  
    register_setting("section", "logo", "handle_logo_upload");
}
add_action("admin_init", "display_theme_panel_fields");
```

The issue is its not saving logo and also not displaying it in admin as well. I have tried this 10 times with different ways but this code is not working. Please look in this code and help me in it please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use wordpress customizer then try this code

```
public static function register ( $wp_customize ) {
    // Logo upload
    $wp_customize->add_section( 'bia_logo_section' , array(
        'title'       => __( 'Site Logo', 'bia' ),
        'priority'    => 30,
        'description' => 'Upload a logo to replace the default site name and description in the header',
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'bia_logo', array(
        'sanitize_callback' => 'esc_url_raw',
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'bia_logo', array(
        'label'    => __( 'Site Logo', 'bia' ),
        'section'  => 'bia_logo_section',
        'settings' => 'bia_logo',
    ) ) );
}
```

i think you can also try [redux framework](https://reduxframework.com/) for admin panel option

Comment: HI buddy i am making it with custom code for a practice purpose so. now only one issue which is left in my above code is after saving a logo if i save it again it goes blank and replace the current updated logo. i am looking for its solution only now.

Comment: Hi i think you can check this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nvsK0cTH0So

Answer (score 2):

Since version 4.5 the [Theme Logo](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Logo) is a standard feature of WordPress. You can simply add the following code to your `functions.php`:

```
function wpse237461_theme_logo() {
    add_theme_support( 'custom-logo', array(
        'height'      => 100,
        'width'       => 400,
        'flex-width' => true ) );
    }
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse237461_theme_logo' );
```

Now you can change the logo in the theme customizer and you can add it to your theme with `the_custom_logo()`. No need to handle files and options yourself.

Comment: HI i have done this and code is working fine. only issue which is comming in it now is if person again save the logo without adding image it show blank option.